# SSIS 2008: Changing a Data Source's Connection String Not Reflecting in Referencing Packages

Tags: ssis, connection-string, datasource

Been struggling with this for quite some time so any help is appreciated. Spent a lot of time looking over MSDN, Google, etc, and still no luck.

I have an SSIS project I intent to always execute from within BID. The project has multiple packages, so I created a Data Source to share amongst all the packages.

In each package, I create a Connection Manager based of that Data Source. Now when I go and edit this Data Source's connection string to point to a different server, the change is NOT reflected in the packages.

Now, MSDN says the opposite. In fact, one of the main purposes of Data Sources is to update connection strings easily from within BID; at least according to MSDN.

And for me its not working. This has got to be the most annoying thing I have seen thus far in BID.

Any one have any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
It looks like BID does not synchronize a Data Source change with Connection Managers if the data source's authentication is SQL server. If it is Windows authentication, it detects the change fine.

Very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out for those that are interested. I am not sure if this is a bug in BID or not but I hope this helps someone else struggling with this problem.

All you have to do is simply open up all your packages at one time. This is as simple as highlighting all the packages in the solution, right clicking, and choose "open".

Once all the packages have been opened, go ahead and edit your Data Source's connection properties. BID will automatically apply the new changes to all the **open** packages that have a connection manager based on that Data source.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'd consider if abandoning "Data Sources" and switching to "Package Configurations" was more appropriate or not. I've never used data sources because my applications must be transparently deployed to development, test and production. Any per-environment changes are against the law, as this would completely invalidate any prior testing that was done. Instead, the configuration database on each server environment stores complete knowledge of that environments details, so the packages just work no matter where you put them. If something does change then its just a config entry, not a redeploy.

Comment: @tlum any more info on how to use package configurations?  i think that's the solution i'd preer

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess. This kind of behavior happens when you have a "package configuration" configured.

Right click on any blank area of your control flow and select "package configuration". If the "Enable package configurations" check box is selected and you have a configuration on your connection string, it will override any value you had specified manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had package configuration turned off though. I did finally figure it out; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I found I could not change any of the data connection configuration values because there was a variable defined for the connection string. Enabling/disabling package configurations had no effect on the behavior.

To access the variables menu, right click anywhere on the DTSX designer background and select *Variables*. Make sure you do not have any values in the variables list that are being referenced by your data connection. If you can not find the references anywhere, try fixing the values for the variables that might be affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in respective dtsx package. Open it in notepad++ and search for the connection string, modify it and save it. You can see the connection change in solution now.